# Opencart Weight Based Shipping

Tags: mysql, arrays, opencart

I have alot of scripts that do various different things outside opencart, but using the opencart database.  They don't modify the database simply query it for the purpose of reporting and alike.

I want to query to the OpenCart database and the standard weight based shipping rates (domestic, uk).  At the minute I cannot even figure out where those weight based shipping costs are stored, never mind look up the shipping price against the product.

```
$delivery_query=mysql_query("SELECT value FROM `oc_setting` T1 where T1.group = 'weight' and T1.key = 'weight_4_rate'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($delivery_query)){
 $delivery=explode(',',$row['value']);
 foreach($delivery as $rate){
  $delivery_arry[]=explode(':',$rate);
 }
}
```

Which is producing my delivery array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 1.58
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 250
            [1] => 1.96
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
            [1] => 2.48
```

Looping through my second array from the oc_products table I have outputted another array of products with weight, within that loop I need to lookup the price for the corresponding weight...  **This is now the bit I need help with!?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shipping costs are stored in the `setting` table, or `oc_setting` in your case. For the standard weight based shipping, the rates are stored with the key `weight_X_rate` where `X` is the geozone id, and have the group `weight`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jay, presumably I want to explode the values into an array, but I am a little unsure as to look the correct weight from it.  Got any pointers?

Comment: Easiest way of doing it is to replicate what the model for the shipping method on the catalog side does it. `/catalog/model/shipping/weight.php` - you essentially need to explode twice per rate

Comment: I updated my question, I have the array of prices and weights, from my second products array group how do I find the price for the weight?

Comment: Find this line in the model `foreach ($rates as $rate) {` - that is how the model does it. basically as soon as it finds a weight that is higher than the current rate, it breaks and uses the last found price that didn't go over the weight limit

Comment: OK I'm nearly there, just need help building the $rates array from my sql query.  $delivery_query=mysql_query("SELECT value FROM `oc_setting` T1 where T1.group = 'weight' and T1.key = 'weight_4_rate'");  Can't seem to get that right.

Comment: you mean how do you select the data using php and mysql? outside of opencart?

Comment: yes, that mysql select query needs to be presented as an array to hand datato the $rates = explode(',', portion of the code right?

Comment: When you select it, it will return the rate as a string, which you then manipulate using explodes. mysql doesn't need to return an array of data